# Can we access the "Feed" as per the mobile app on Desktop?

Tags: feature-request, android-app-feed

The mobile app has a "Feed" screen (pictured). I really like this "at a glance" screen. Is there a way we can see this on the desktop of any SE site (like Stack Overflow)? If there already is somewhere like this.. I apologise.

[image: feed]

Comment: It'd be nice on stackexchange.com

Comment: Good news: it's planned. Bad news: not in the near future.