# About tags for specific features of official mobile apps

Tags: discussion, support, tags, meta

There are some "sub-tags" for tags regarding the official Android and iOS apps for Stack Exchange.

- [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) - 433 questions tagged

  - [ios-app-feed](/questions/tagged/ios-app-feed) - 15
- [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) - 918

  - [android-app-feed](/questions/tagged/android-app-feed) - 30
  - [android-app-widgets](/questions/tagged/android-app-widgets) - 6

Why do we need them? Does this really help filter the meta questions?

If a user tags a meta question with a so-called "sub-tag" (e.g. [android-app-feed](/questions/tagged/android-app-feed)), does the user have to tag the question with the main tag as well (e.g. [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app))? Only [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231450/201738) out of the 51 sub-tag questions does **not** have the main tag - the rest follow this convention.

Whatever the answer is to the above question, should we add/modify the tag excerpts to tell the potential tag users about it?

Comment: Because some people really like creating tags.

Comment: Yeah, you might see *"ios-app-widgets"* pretty soon, now that **iOS 8** has some weird form of a widget system. I would deem it better to have the tag focus on the specific feature of mobile platforms in general, rather than on a specific platform. For example, the *"ios-app-feed"* and *"android-app-feed"* tags should be combined to simply **one** *"app-feed"* or *"mobile-app-feed"* tag (with the possible sub-tags as synonyms to help tag search). Which platform the question is for, should be visible from the platform tag: *"ios-app"* or *"android-app"*.

Answer (score 1):

Not a formal answer, but in my opinion sub tag alone is not enough, it's just used as a "bonus", giving extra details about the question contents.

Using the main tag ([ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app) or [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app)) is a must, so that it will be easily available when looking in the specific tag. Adding a sub tag is optional, used to "zoom in" on the topic.

As for tag excerpts those are always useful and yes, anyone is welcome to create/improve them.

Comment: I think it is better to have the tag focus on the specific feature of **mobile platforms in general**. The job of identifying the platform should be left to the main tag, or we are simply having redundant information in the tags. See my relevant comment (792054) on question.

Comment: @ADTC problem is, each such platform got a different team working on it. Sometimes same bug/request can be done on one platform and not the other.

Comment: That's why I mentioned using the main tag to identify the platform, and the feature tag to identify the feature *only*. Like [mobile-app-feed] would tell you this question is about site feed in mobile apps, and [android-app] would tell you this question is regarding the Android app. *Nett result:* The question is about site feed in the Android app.

Comment: **And if** a question applies to the site feed equally in all platforms (like a feature request seeking to improve something about the site feed), it should only need one tag (mobile-app-feed), rather than four tags (ios-app, ios-app-feed, android-app, android-app-feed).